# Count similar strings as the same name in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift, how can we treat similar strings as the same name so we can get the correct count?  For example, the column school_name can have the same school in different variances:

```
Spring Creek Elementary
Spring Creek Elementary School
Spring Creek
```

So count(distinct school_name) should be 1 and not 3.

Comment: Note:one is a non-empty (left) substring of the other.

Comment: Did you mean using split_part(schoolname,' ', 1) to get the first word of schoolname and just count the unique first word?

Comment: Why dont you try? (the other option is position(), or left(), with some treshold)

Comment: Determining what counts as a "similar" string can be a complex computing problem. e.g. do you want "Springs Creek" and "Spring Crook" to also match? It might help if you are able to get a definitive list of correct strings (e.g. school names) to compare to. Redshift doesn't have any native capabilities to compare inexact matches of strings, but it's possible to create python UDFs to help with this, for example https://community.periscopedata.com/t/y7kxrc